# Can't fill my model with a grouped list of a table using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm working on a new project using .NET MVC4 and Entity Framework. I have a products table and i'm trying to select products with grouping.

My model:

```
public class Cart
{
    public long Index { get; set; }
    public List<Products> ProductList = new List<Products>();
    public int ItemCount { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
}
```

My Query:

```
var result = from p in productList
             group p by p.id into grp
             select new
             {
                 Index = grp.Key,
                 ProductList = grp.ToList<Products>(),
                 ItemCount = grp.Count(),
                 Total = grp.Sum(w => w.price)
             };
```

And then i wanted to apply result to a List of Cart. But i failed at some point. Please can you help me to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the type returned by your `select`

```
var result = from p in productList
             group p by p.id into grp
             select new Cart  //<-- here
             {
                 Index = grp.Key,
                 ProductList = grp.ToList<Products>(),
                 ItemCount = grp.Count(),
                 Total = grp.Sum(w => w.price)
             };
```

now `result` is of type `IEnumerable<Cart>`. You could add an extra `ToList()` to make it `List<Cart>`:

```
List<Cart> lst = result.ToList();
```